# Is it possible to compact the VC++ runtime heap?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, runtime, heap-memory

Can I have the same effect as with [`HeapCompact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366598(VS.85).aspx) for the Visual C++ runtime heap? How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "run-time heap"? What other sort is there?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I mean the one which is used by malloc(). In Win32 the program can create additional heaps with HeapCreate().

Comment: Out of interest, is there an astonishingly good reason that free block coalescing isn't happening automatically? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265897.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a HANDLE for the CRT heap using _get_heap_handle, then call HeapCompact on it.  Not sure whether this is supported/stable as I have not tried this myself.  I imagine you would want to call HeapCompact in serialized mode to have any chance of this working.

If you are going to this trouble just call HeapSetInformation on the handle (per MDSN docs on _get_heap_handle) and let the built-in LFH handle compaction for you.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC not without writing your own memory manager. It's also a non-trivial piece of work, especially if you expect to do more than just combining adjacent smaller empty memory blocks into larger ones.

Comment: In fact combining adjacent blocks is the only thing HeapCompact() does.

Comment: You'd have to *really* need to do this for there not to be a better idea.

Comment: Yes, one reason for memory allocation failure is heap fragmentation. In case `malloc()` returns `NULL` you can try to `HeapCompact(GetProcessHeap(),0)`, cross your fingers and then `malloc()` again. Actually a bad solution but it may help when the time is tight. You should really optimize/alter the memory allocation strategy of the program, e.g. using memory-mapped files ([link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/dd997372.aspx) and [link2](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/General_optimization_techniques/Input/Output#Memory-mapped_file)).